# ArcGIS Bug? (Script Parameter Property: Obtained From)

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm currently having problem with *Obtained From* properties in script parameter

When i clicked the *Obtained From* panel, it should have show a dropdown list (in here i use to obtain things from dataset data types).

**But Now I cannot do it anymore**

I could not even edit the chosen *Obtained from* from earlier paramater that i have used.

[image]

I wonder what could make it so? i need to fix it fast...

I think it's happened after i edit the **Validation** tab in Script Properties.

in default it should have shown like this

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

Then i edited it to this, so i can *get specific value from column*

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if self.params[1].value and self.params[2].value:
        self.params[3].filter.list = sorted({row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.params[1].value, self.params[2].value.value) if row[0]})

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

Dunno if that triggers something or not, I have reverted the changes but nothing works...Did I clicked something else? I don't think so

Comment: It affect other script properties too, i tried to reinstall the ArcGIS..... doesn't solve anything

Comment: This is strange, in the morning i could obtain input from dataset, now i cannot...

I found another workaround, kinda strange too...
So i set the "dataset" datatypes, to "table" datatypes

From there, now the "Obtained From" panel could go on using "Field" Datatypes...

Then i change "table" back to "dataset"

That works...